# Memory leak using ARC being indicated in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Somehow I am seeing memory increase in my simulator (the running bar graph).

I have an object called `MyObject` which has nothing but an `int`. In some other class (say `MyCar` in MyCar.h) I have an array of `MyObject`s, e.g. `MyObject* junk[8];`

and a method to return a specific one by index:

```
-(MyObject*) getJunk:(int) index{
    if(junk[index] == nil){
        return nil;
    }
    return junk[index];
}
```

In another class called `DataModel` I have a `MyCar *mycar;`

in `DataModel` I call a method `ask`

```
-(void) ask{
    if(mycar == nil){
        return nil;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if( [mycar getJunk:i] == nil){
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

I call `[self ask]` say 10,000 times each time. I am using ARC, but I notice each time the iOS memory bar goes up. So something is accumulating memory; I don't know what, I don't have any `alloc`s. Yes, this happens even if I write such non useless code which does nothing with the `junk[i]` returned to data model.

I even tried

```
-(void) ask{
    if(mycar == nil){
        return nil;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        MyObject* temp_junk = [mycar getJunk:i];
        if( temp_junk == nil){
            continue;
        }
        temp_junk = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating the objects that go into the array? Have you run the analyzer over this code, or used Instruments? Where is the leak indicated?

Comment: Do you use Zombie objects enabled in diagnostics? It seems so.

Comment: Using the allocations tool, you can see which objects are being allocated and using up memory. That should give you a clue to where to look.

Comment: It's possible ARC is autoreleasing the return value from getJunk; that may cause additional memory to be used in the autorelease pool until it's flushed, which will normally happen at the end of the event.  But in that case most of the memory should eventually be reclaimed.  What happens if you put @autoreleasepool { ... } around the for loop?

Comment: Do you have an autorelease block inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. Carl, Hot Licks the autorelease did it. So looks like the time of the flush is not predictable unless you use autorelease. My code was really simple and I was not running any tools. I am absolutely Fresh of the boat when it comes to objective C and iOS :-) getting the tools setup and how to use it today.

Comment: @magellan_tor Any reason for using a C MyObject[] array and not an NSArray? In simple cases, storing NSObjects in a C-array just works, in other cases, it's very easy to mangle the memory management / size requirements. Not that you did, but it's a concern -- especially where NSArray just works.

Comment: The memory probably wasn't the objects themselves, if your code is actually representative -- it would be autoreleasing the same object over and over again.  However, the autorelease pool does have to get bigger to hold every autoreleased object until it gets flushed.  So, flushing periodically means the autorelease pool itself won't keep getting bigger, which was probably more of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `[self ask]` 10000 times in a loop, like this:

```
for (int = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    [self ask];
```

then you are accumulating autoreleased objects inside the loop - those objects will not be released until your loop ends and the main run loop flushes the autorelease pool.  Try creating your own autorelease pool inside your loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        [self ask];
    }
}
```

That will create a new pool each time through the loop and flush it each time so those autoreleased objects will go away.

Comment: Josh, yes this worked. As I commented above, looks like you can't predict when ARC will release.